# Identify Cause of Serialization Error Coming From Inside Library/NuGet Package

Tags: c#, api, mastercard

Sometimes when calling the Mastercard MATCH API via the NuGet package MasterCard-Match, I will get a JSON deserialization exception:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '',
>   line 0, position 0.

The exception is from MasterCard.Core with an inner exception from Newtonsoft.Json, both have the same message.

It looks like I'm receiving HTML ('<' at line 0, position 0) and the library is trying to deserialize it as JSON. My guess is that the MasterCard API is sending back an HTML error page instead of a JSON error. But I can't step into the function call to "see" the response its getting before throwing the exception.

As per the [documentation](https://developer.mastercard.com/documentation/match/3) I create a request map with the provided data and call `TerminationInquiryRequest.Create(map)`, this is the line the exception is thrown. This function call is a black box, I can't step into it, it just throws the exception.

```cs
try
{
  RequestMap requestMap = CreateRequestMap(); 

  // This line throws the exception
  TerminationInquiryRequest apiResponse = TerminationInquiryRequest.Create(requestMap);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  // Exception handling
}
```

I've made over 11,000+ calls using this library and only 32 have had this error, but of course I get to hear about it every time it happens.

Is there any way to debug libraries that I'm not aware of, or a way to view the response that the library is getting from the API?

I already have some logic to wait and retry the call if it fails.

Comment: At worst you could use Wireshark to trace the network but how useful would that be? Whatever the error you will retry anyway right? And why do you hear about it? Are you rethrowing the exception?